# Lego Mindstorms EV3: programming language recommendation

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, nxt, ev3-g, ev3dev

I am planning to build an autonomous car in LEGO Mindstorms that will use ultrasonic or infrared sensors and in the future also a camera for line tracking. Currently I construct my programs using the Mindstorms building blocks, however, I am wondering whether I should switch to a different programming language such as C/C++ or Java to have more flexibility especially regarding lane tracking algorithms with the camera. In this regard I have the following questions:

1. In general, would you recommend switching to a normal programming language (I am quite "fluent" in languages like C/C++, Python and Java) in order to avoid having to use blocks when building more complex programs?
2. If so, which programming language would you recommend? I feel like there is a big community for leJOS and Java which is definitely a plus, although I could imagine that considering the fact that I would like to integrate a camera a language like C/C++ that works well with MATLAB or OpenCV for line tracking algorithms might also not be bad - what do you think would be the best idea for my use case?
3. Is it possible to use a different programming language without flashing my EV3 such that I can switch back to building blocks if I wanted to?

Thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 8):

> 1. In general, would you recommend switching to a normal programming language (I am quite "fluent" in languages like C/C++, Python and Java) in order to avoid having to use blocks when building more complex programs?

Yes, especially if you plan on doing image processing.

> 2. If so, which programming language would you recommend? I feel like there is a big community for leJOS and Java which is definitely a plus, although I could imagine that considering the fact that I would like to integrate a camera a language like C/C++ that works well with MATLAB or OpenCV for line tracking algorithms might also not be bad - what do you think would be the best idea for my use case?

I'd recommend using [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org/), as it seems more-powerful and leJOS development appears inactive.

ev3dev has [a few languages you can chose from](http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/programming-languages/), though your choice may be limited somewhat by which languages support the image processing libraries you want to use.

> 3. Is it possible to use a different programming language without flashing my EV3 such that I can switch back to building blocks if I wanted to?

With ev3dev, you run the software off a removable micro SD card. No need to replace the internal firmware.

Comment: Absolutely agree to that. I recently started with **ev3dev** and set up cross compiling via docker image. https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/how-to-cross-compile-for-ev3dev-using-docker