# LEGO Mindstorms EV3: Camera recommendation for line tracking

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, ev3-g

I am planning to build an autonomous car in LEGO Mindstorms that will use ultrasonic or infrared sensors for collision avoidance and in the future also a camera for line tracking. I am now wondering which camera I should use. Currently, I am considering the following two cameras:

1. [The Pixy LEGO Camera](http://cmucam.org/projects/cmucam5/wiki/LEGO_Wiki)
   It seems to be quite good for object tracking, however, I am not sure whether it will work well for line tracking.
2. [The NXTCam-v4](http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/14-vision-subsystem-camera-for-nxt-or-ev3-nxtcam-v4?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=78)
   Judging from the videos on [3](http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/14-vision-subsystem-camera-for-nxt-or-ev3-nxtcam-v4?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=78) line tracking should work quite well with this camera.

I am leaning towards the NXTCam but I wanted to get some other opinions before investing money ;) Therefore, your view on things is greatly appreciated, especially regarding which camera is best for lane tracking and which camera has a good API to use it with a different programming language than the LEGO building blocks (so for example to leJOS, RobotC, ...). Thank you!

Comment: I've not used either, but judging from the docs for the Pixy cam, it's more for "trained object recognition" - so if you're avoiding known objects you might be ok, but otherwise it might not be great. That said, the original Mindstorms used the colour/light sensor to do line tracking and path following - assuming a track on the ground with sufficient contrast was available.

Comment: There is now a NXTCam-v5 which, as far as I can tell, can do everything the PixyCam can do and more.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Yes, I know that you can use colour/light sensors for line tracking. However, I am aiming for a more realistic autonomous car hence line tracking should be achieved via a camera. Thanks for the comment anyway!

Comment: @DavidLechner Alright, that is good to know. There is also an EV3-G building block for the NXTCam - would you use that one or would you recommend switching to a different programming language for accurate line tracking (f.ex. leJOS with OpenCV)? (see https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9295/lego-mindstorms-ev3-programming-language-recommendation)

Comment: FYI, there is such a thing as PixyCam2 which has some improvements from the old one, and it supports line-tracking. Never heard of NXTcam though.